# Is this equation solvable for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is is possible to solve this equation for x?

$$ \frac{x}{q} + \frac{x}{(1-xk)^2} - t = 0 $$

x, q, k, t are all Real and positive.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Add the fractions, multiply by $q(1 - x k)^2$ and clean up. You should get a cubic, with a bit of luck it won't give only horrible roots with [Cardan's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Comment: @vonbrand: Would you recommend Cardano's formula over Vieta's?  Are there circumstances in which one will be more straightforward than the other?

Comment: I only know it as Cardano's formula... Vieta's formulas give the coefficients in terms of the roots. In any case, the formula is quite nasty, if you can guess a root it reduces to a more manageable quadratic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute 
$$y = (1-xk)$$
then
$$x=\frac{1-y}{k}$$
Substituting $x$ in the given equation

$$ \frac{x}{q} + \frac{x}{(1-xk)^2} - t = 0 $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1-y}{k.q} + \frac{1-y}{k.y^2}-t=0$$
$$\Rightarrow k.y^2-k.y^3+k.q-k.q.y=t.k^2.y^2.q$$
$$\Rightarrow k.y^2-k.y^3+k.q-k.q.y-t.k^2.y^2.q=0$$
$$\Rightarrow -k.y^3+k.y^2-k.q.y+k.q-t.k^2.y^2.q=0$$
$$\Rightarrow -k.y^3+k.y^2-k.q.y+k.q-tq.(ky)^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow -k.y^3+k.y^2-tq.k^2.y^2-k.q.y+k.q=0$$
$$\Rightarrow -k.y^3+k.y^2(1-t.q.k)-k.q.y+k.q=0$$
$$\Rightarrow y^3-y^2(1-t.q.k)+q.y-q=0$$
$$\Rightarrow y^3+y^2(t.q.k-1)+q.y-q=0$$
Solving for y in the cubic equation would give you the result
$$- \frac{1}{3} k q t + \frac{\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}}} - \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}} + \frac{1}{3}$$

---

$$- \frac{1}{3} k q t + \frac{\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}}{\left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \mathbf{\imath}\right) \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}}} - \left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \mathbf{\imath}\right) \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}} + \frac{1}{3}$$

---

$$- \frac{1}{3} k q t + \frac{\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}}{\left(- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \mathbf{\imath}\right) \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}}} - \left(- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \mathbf{\imath}\right) \sqrt[3]{- \frac{1}{6} q \left(k q t -1\right) + \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3} q - \frac{1}{9} \left(k q t -1\right)^{2}\right)^{3} + \frac{1}{4} \left(- \frac{1}{3} q \left(k q t -1\right) + q + \frac{2}{27} \left(k q t -1\right)^{3}\right)^{2}}} + \frac{1}{3}$$

Then determine $x$ by substituting $y$ in  $$x=\frac{1-y}{k}$$

Comment: This turns out to be a complicated equation(If we plug in the $x$).?

Comment: Am I right that the term on the end $-t.q.(k.y)^2$ should be combined with the $k.y^2$ term to give $(k-t.q.k^2)y^2$ ?

Comment: @apo: Yes you should. I have actually overlooked in the equation. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Can divide through by $-k$, that simplifies it a bit. But it doesn't seem to have any easy roots/factorizations :-(

Comment: @Abhijit: wow, thanks for writing that out explicitly.  What method did you use to solve the cubic equation for y?  Cardano? Vieta? or something else?

Comment: I was just looking over this again to make sure I understand all the steps, and I think there is a small error in the last two cubic equations $$y3−y2(1−t.q.k)+q.y+q=0$$
$$y3+y2(t.q.k−1)+q.y+q=0$$ I think they should end with $-q$ not $+q$.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply through by $(1-xk)^2$ and expand, you will get a cubic polynomial in $x$, which you may or may not be able to solve depending on the values of those constants.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is solvable regardless of the values of the coefficients,since according to Galois theory, every algebraic equation with its degree less than 5 can be expressed as a "closed" form in terms of its coefficients,and your equation can be transformed to a cubic equation by multiplying $(1-kx)^2$ by each side. 
However,the expression is often very complicated(See [Cubic Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots) on Wikipedia),so sometimes solving them numerically may be a better idea.